# Another crossbar in american football

Tags: american-football, nfl

Could anyone tell me, why there is no crossbar on the upper side of the uprights in american football? It would make officiating difficult situations easier. Is there an engineering reason? Is it about tradition? I know that ball (american football ball :)) could fly to 100 feet but if it's beetwen imagined extensions of uprights than it's a good kick. "Upper" crossbar would solve those dilemmas.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean. Where do you mean by "the upper side"?

Comment: @ user16112: I am sorry that my question looks like a rant. I guess my choice of words wasn't good. I just wanted to know, why there is no second "upper" crossbar in american football (or rugby union), because it would make deciding whether kick ended as a field goal (i don't know expresion for rugby union) much easier in some cases (ball flying over uprights). I apologise if my choices of words and expresions caused any inconvenience.

Comment: Maybe i should have asked if there ever was a discussion about adding "upper" crossbar in american football or rugby union.

Comment: @OgnjenMojovic I have deleted my prior comment as you have clearly and pleasantly explained your intent. The claims you make regarding the benefits of an upper crossbar are ostensible. For example, the officials would have to determine whether or not the ball traveled over the upper crossbar. I would imagine that would be more difficult since they have to look up about 45 feet high, sometimes in dark and/or inclement conditions. Such circumstances would almost always have to rely on instant replay to provide a definitive call.

Comment: @user16112: Well, that is a good reason to not have a crossbar at the height of 45 feet. Of course, i know that they have a good reason to not have it, but i didn't know what it is.

Comment: @OgnjenMojovic History shows that the uprights were only 20 and 30 feet long respectively. If we attach an upper crossbar to that, the kickers would have to drive their kick lower, meaning the probability said kick gets blocked is higher.

Comment: @user16112: When i look NFL on tv, making field goals looks easy, but when i visualies what kicker sees and what angles you have to make with the oblong ball, i guess it's not that easy.

Answer (score 4):

Because there's no upper bound to a field goal being good (the line of the uprights extend upwards infinitely). You would be laughed at for even suggesting that there should be an upper bound on field goals. Also, field goals that pass just above the uprights are pretty rare to begin with.